# jQuery on, add only one event listener

Tags: jquery

I have an event listener for a ul:

```
$('body').on('click.submenu', '.top-level', subMenu);
```

Is there a way to ensure that it only gets added once?

The reason being, I only need this added when the viewport is at a "mobile" breakpoint, and when it goes from desktop back to mobile, there seems to be more than one event listener.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var body = $("body");                             //Store for later use
if(!(body.data("EventAdded") === true)){            //Test if event was added
    body.data("EventAdded", true)                     //If not, set EventAdded as true
        .on('click.submenu', '.top-level', subMenu);  //and add the event
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The only thing I can think of is calling `off` on it before you add the listener

```
$('body').off('click.submenu', '.top-level', subMenu);
$('body').on('click.submenu', '.top-level', subMenu);
```